Flutter Firebase require resign in to work
I am using Firebase Auth and Firestore,
it works fine but when close the app for a while( more than 30 mins approximately)
no firebase code work and i get the following error:
W/System  (12108): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
4
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(12108): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
D/TrafficStats(12108): tagSocket(129) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
3
W/Firestore(12108): (24.11.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get auth token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked. ].
W/Firestore(12108): (24.11.0) [WatchStream]: (1565506) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=null, cause=com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked. ]
W/Firestore(12108):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzach.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.3.1:18)
W/Firestore(12108):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.3.1:21)
.
.
W/Firestore(12108):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/Firestore(12108):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/Firestore(12108):     at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
W/Firestore(12108):     at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
W/Firestore(12108):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/Firestore(12108): }.
W/Firestore(12108): (24.11.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=null, cause=com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked. ]

and no firebase write work till i sign out and sign in again, anyone, i tried the possible solutions Here and Here
i am using a real device for debugging
but nothing works, here you can ma package name, and firebase package name



I'm pretty sure that Android shuts down network access for apps that are not actively being used.  This prevents malicious or poorly-coded apps from using more network than the user might expect.  If you want to do background networking, consider using a dedicated library to enable that correctly, such as WorkManager.

Actually i am not doing any background task for firebase, i just terminate the app and open it after an hour and it require me to sign out and sign in again to be able to write to firestore

On Android, when you use the home button to leave an app, you are not really "terminating" it.  You are just sending it to the background.  Android assumes that the user might want to return to it later and keeps the process running for some time so the can do so quickly.  If your app is logging, then it is still actually running and you haven't terminated anything.

Thanks for explaining, but i preview the working apps and press close all, will it be terminated in this case

Your question should explain exactly the actions you're taking so that it can be clear to others how you're able to reproduce this.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "preview the working apps and press close all". Not all android devices work the same.

To solve this for anyone my face the same problem
the problem was that the API Key was restricted
you have to visit:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID
select the API key you use
and under API restrictions
use
Don't restrict key
